# Best practice for Snapshot artifact publication and release artifact publication

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, ivy

We are using IVY on our project and I have recently setup a Jenkins server so that every time a trunk check in is performed the following happens.

1. Jenkins SCM poll detects change and notifies IVY plugin.
2. IVY plugin triggers ANT build for changed module and triggers build of downstream modules.
3. Built modules are then published to central IVY repo versioned as 1.0-SNAPSHOT

Each module ivy.xml on trunk declares dependencies using rev="latest.integration" and the ivysettings.xml file declares the resolver as follows.  This ensures later SNAPSHOTS are pulled down to the local IVY repo.

```
    <resolvers>
    <chain name="chained" returnFirst="true">
        <filesystem name="libraries" changingPattern="1.0-SNAPSHOT" changingMatcher="exact" checkmodified="true">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.repo.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>           
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.repo.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>
    </chain>
</resolvers>
```

Now this works fine whilst developing on trunk, but I am confused on how to take this forward so that we can publish release artifacts.  If I am correct SNAPSHOTS should never be used in a production deployment?

I was thinking whether to implement a weekly build that runs at the weekend and performs the following.

1. Tears down the Jenkins workspace.
2. Checks out trunk from SVN.
3. Runs a full build and executes all unit tests.
4. If 3 runs to success for ALL modules then publish versioned artifacts eg -WKYY.1 to IVY repo.

Now if steps 1-4 are correct, do I then TAG SVN and create branches for ALL modules so that the IVY.xml files can be checked in which state the correct dependency version numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I can share how we have things setup, although our situation is different.

We have a separate branch for release builds, and a separate job that polls this branch and makes release builds from it. Our release process consists in part of merging the master branch to the release branch. This can be automated of course. In your case, perhaps you could do it if step 3 succeeds.

So for each project we have one set of jobs (tracking "master") that handle the snapshot builds, and one set of jobs (tracking "release") that handle the release builds. The jobs are similar for the most part, but different.

Comment: At what point do you decide to create a release branch?  At the moment, the project I am on all of the developers check in to trunk and release from trunk.  Release branches are never created :-(

Comment: That depends on what you want. You could merge to the release branch whenever a build and all tests succeed. Or you could do it periodically, based on your release schedule. For us it is currently a more or less manual process. We have one big project with many repositories. When we want to have a release, we prohibit all commits except those required to fix failing builds. When all builds are okay, we merge master to release for all repo's.

Comment: Also, we don't create release branches (as in: a separate branch for each release). We have *one* branch called "release" and we merge trunk to that branch whenever the code is stable or when we want a release. So the workflow does not differ that much from when you release from trunk.